# Pygame object class comparision with a tuple

Tags: python, pygame

So i am trying to create a game in pygame. Everything is going well, but I have a problem where I am trying to set the winning condition. For this I made some for loops to go through the rows and columns and without too many details, the point is if the white piece is in the first or the 5th row, the game is won.

```
def winner(self):
    for row in range(ROWS):
        for col in range(COLS):
            piece = self.get_piece(row, col)
            if piece == WHITE:
                print("hello")
                if row == 0:
                    return YELLOW
                if row == 4:
                    return BLUE
```

Both WHITE and piece return (250, 250, 250), but WHITE is a tuple, and piece is a '<class 'mygame.piece.Piece'>' class object, so I guess they are not comparable. I changed my code in the 5th row like this:

```
if piece == Piece(row, col, WHITE):
```

This returns a '<class 'mygame.piece.Piece'>' object as well, but for some reason it still doesn't print hello, meaning it doesn't compare the two object.
My question would be how can I compare two pygame objects? Or can I convert a pygame object to a tuple? I have the same problem with another function. I haven't found anything on this.

Answer (score 0):

`Piece(row, col, WHITE)` creates an new object, so `Piece(row, col, WHITE)` is not equal to `piece`. Objects are not compared attribute-wise unless you implement the comparison method ([`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)).
You need to compare the object's `color` attribute to `WHITE`:

```py
if piece and piece.color == WHITE:
```

If the object doesn't have an attribute `color`, then add one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I started out from the code you suggested, but tried to go in other directions. Now I modified the code to the following: ` if piece != 0 and piece.color == WHITE: `. Apparently the problem was, that there were places with no pieces in them, with the value 0. Excluding them from the if statement made it all work.